# How to easily run java programs in the same package?

Tags: java, compilation, cmd, package, javac

I was trying to make an extension of an existing program and wanted to create another class to help the main one. Ideally, they would both be in the same package and could access each other. I checked through a lot of the other questions and was a little confused by the complexity of some of the compiling methods (new to this). So here is an example of my setup:

I have two classes, one with a main method both in the same package, "cereal.crunchy".

Class 1: Important
Class 2: Junk

```
$ cd ~/Desktop/cereal/
$ javac crunchy/*.java
$ java crunchy/Important
```

I got the error

```
Could not find or load main class
```

Both have package declarations:

```
package cereal.crunchy;
```

Everything is public.

What confuses me is that  when I compile them using the previously mentioned method and then do

```
$ cd ~/Desktop/
$ java cereal/crunchy/important
```

The program runs and can access the other class.

I guess I just don't understand why I can't do:

```
$ cd ~/Desktop/cereal/
$ javac crunchy/*.java
$ java crunchy/Important
```

(Please help me, I understand that this question is really unpolished, however I looked at other questions and did not see any simple answers).
(Not for school, something I am doing on my own).

Answer (score 2):

When you run a Java program, you specify the package and the class

Packages are not the same as directories.

1. Although the separator for directories is `/`, the separator for packages is `.`.

   In other words, you would have to do:

   ```
   java crunchy.Important
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   java crunchy/Important
   ```
2. Since the package of `Important` is `cereal.crunchy`, it won't work if it's in the directory `crunchy`. It has to be in the directory `cereal/crunchy`.

   In other words, `cereal` has to be in the current directory.

So, you would do it like this:

```
java cereal.crunchy.important
```

Comment: Thanks so much! In a previous class we never did package declarations, and just used cd to get to the directory of the file then compiled and ran it. I thought that you had to leave a package statement all the time describing the file path. Thanks!